# ios-all pages in scrollview not loading with custom uiview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview, uiscrollview

Custom uiview gets loaded only on first page, Here is code I am working on:

```
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var customframe: CGRect!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    customframe = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: self.scrollView.frame.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.height)

    scrollView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    scrollView.layer.cornerRadius = scrollView.frame.height/4
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.loadScrollView()
}
func loadScrollView() {
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.frame.size.width * 5, height: scrollView.frame.size.height)
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    for i in 0..<5 {
        print(self.scrollView.frame.size.width)

        let progressChartView = ProgressChartView(frame: customframe)//initialise cgdraw
        progressChartView.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.scrollView.addSubview(progressChartView)

    }
}
```

Here progressChartView is instance of subclass of UIView which I want to populate in all of the 5 pages of scrollView, but it loads only in first page.

Please help, if I have missed something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if some body faces issue with overlapping of views in scrollView, use this instead what given in the accepted answer:                                              
`let frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i)*( self.scrollView.frame.size.width ), y: 0, width: self.scrollView.frame.size.width, height: self.scrollView.frame.size.height)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting multiple  `ProgressChartView` at the same position

Replace  your code

```
 for i in 0..<5 {
        print(self.scrollView.frame.size.width)

        let progressChartView = ProgressChartView(frame: customframe)//initialise cgdraw
        progressChartView.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.scrollView.addSubview(progressChartView)

    }
```

With

```
for i in 0..<5 {
        print(self.scrollView.frame.size.width)
        let frame = CGRect(x: i *  self.scrollView.frame.origin.x,y:0,width:self.scrollView.frame.size.width,height:self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
        let progressChartView = ProgressChartView(frame: frame)//initialise cgdraw
        progressChartView.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.scrollView.addSubview(progressChartView)

    }
```

Comment: @Raj Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi, I have got another issue with this, other consecutive views are getting overlapped over each other.

Comment: @Raj Just check the frame !! that's it all about. you can debug and print the frame of each view .